# BigInteger exponentiation with negative number

Tags: java, python, algorithm, security, encryption

How can I do the same as in this python (using sage) code:

```
def elGamalDecrypt(c1, c2, p, x):
    return Mod(c2*c1^(-x),p)
```

with standard Java 7 libraries? All numbers are `BigInteger`.

I've tried a lot with no avail. In Python it's really simple and FAST.

Comment: ? `^` is bitwise xor in Python, not exponentiation; and no function is required for modulo, as the `%` operator suffices.

Comment: A bitwise xor in el gamal is certainly wrong. And unless the compiler has some special optimizations for an exponentiation+modulo, writing it as separate operations would be extremely slow and memory intensive.

Comment: Of course, if any crypto function is missing from Java, you should probably first try the Bouncy Castle libs, they certainly perform El-Gamal encryption/decryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BigInteger class in Java 7 has a [`modPow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)) method, which handles modular exponentiation.  So, something like the following should work (although I haven't tested it):

```
c2.multiply(c1.modPow(x.negate(), p)).mod(p)
```

The `modPow` method will only accept a negative exponent `-x` if `c1` and `p` are coprime.  (The name `p` suggests that `p` is prime, and if `c1` and `p` aren't coprime, `c1` would be divisible by `p`, and hence the exponentiation would make no sense, so I suspect that this won't be a problem.)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get the link direct to the `modPow` method to quite work.  SO won't accept the full name as a link because it has spaces in it.

Comment: I suppose `-x` should be `x.negate()`, right? I've never worked with java before...

Comment: Ok so I've tested it. `c2.multiply(c1.modPow(x.negate(), p)).mod(p)` seems to work. Is this right?

Comment: @Flavius: I believe you're right.  I did say I hadn't tested it!  I've now updated my answer.  Working with `BigInteger`s in Java is a bit awkward because you have to use methods instead of the regular arithmetic operators.

Comment: Please add a `.mod(p)` to the end and I'll accept it. I've run a couple of tests too and it's definitely needed.

Comment: @Flavius: I agree, the `.mod(p)` is definitely needed to ensure the multiplication takes place modulo p as well as the exponentiation.  Sorry for missing it out - I've now added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the same since `c2 * c1^-x =  c2 / (c1 ^ x)`:

```
BigInteger elGamalDecrypt(BigInteger c1, BigInteger c2, BigInteger p, int x) {
    return c2.divide(c1.pow(x)).mod(p);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is doing modular exponentiation here, in which case your answer wouldn't help.

Comment: @LukeWoodward why not? modular exponentiation is by definition the same as exponentiation followed by modulo, right? that's just inefficient.

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work. As I said, all numbers are BigInteger, and at runtime I get `pow(int) in java.math.BigInteger cannot be applied to (java.math.BigInteger)`. And yes, it's about modular exponentiation, but I have no idea how to do it in java.

Comment: Yes, it was a long shot... the Java BigInteger just supports `modPow`. I guess you have to rearrange the expression so you can use `modPow`

Comment: @harold: modular exponentiation to negative exponents is not the same as doing normal exponentiation and taking the remainder after division by the modulus.  For example, `5^-95 (mod 97)` is 5, whereas 5^-95 is a very small number and taking the remainder of that after division by 97 will not give you 5.

Comment: @LukeWoodward of course, that it why you use the multiplicative inverse of the base..